# Could the EU "take Britain to the Hague" over the "£50 Billion EU divorce bill"

Tags: politics, economics, united-kingdom

I've seen several papers ([express](http://www.express.co.uk/news/politics/743999/Britain-forced-pay-50-billion-leave-European-Union-brexit), [telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/02/01/britain-charged-50-billion-brexit-divorce-bill-sir-ivan-rogers/)) claiming that Britain will have to pay a £50 Billion 'fee' for leaving the EU. A further paper ([Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/germany-uk-the-hague-international-court-not-pay-50-billion-brexit-divorce-bill-warn-a7653621.html)) has written (emphasis by me):

> “In that case it is: **see you in The Hague**!” it quoted an EU official – in response to suggestions that Britain will try to avoid any exit bill.

Is this an actual possibility for refusing an exit *bill**?

*Bill, rather than agreements:

> “I don't know about £50bn, I've seen £40bn, £50bn, £60bn, I've seen no explanation for any of them,” Mr Davis told BBC’s Question Time programme.
>
> “We'll of course meet our international obligations but we expect also our rights to be respected too. I don't think we're going to be seeing that sort of money change hands.

**Is this just a confusion of terms and the obligations and "divorce fee" are one and the same? Or is there an extra fee that the EU intends to take Britain to court over if it doesn't pay it?**

Comment: This is a good question though it might be a better fit on [law.se].

Comment: This is a political question, and belongs on the Politics site.

Comment: This is not about one single "bill", or "divorce fee" (as in "punishment"). This is about what happens to obligations Britain entered into with the 2014-2020 EU budget (which has been planned with), what happens with costs incurred due to EU offices having to relocate away from Britain, and a lot of other things. That is (part of) what the UK and EU will have to negotiate about in the months to come. With rhetoric rather pointed on both sides (as sadly common in more recent politics), it's natural to see extreme positions taken at first, as to not to give in too early. Very sad. ;-)